# How to combine all git commits into one commit if there are others inbetween?

Tags: git

how to combine all of my commits into one git hash, if there are other commits in between of my logs ?,

```
e.g

asdadf = mine
sdffdf = other dev
34234a = another dev
asdfaf = other dev
23423a = mine
a23232 = another dev
asdfsd = other
adsf23 = mine
asdfa= = anotherdev
23423a = anotherdev
```

I want to combine all of mine in one commit only? how to do that if there are other commits in between mine,because
I worry that other commits from other people might have built on top of mine....

Comment: Look at `git rebase --interactive`, you can reorder and squash the series as you like.

Comment: You can't do this, not without interactive rebase or filter branch, as well as seriously reordering the history of your branch.  Perhaps you could tell us why you think you need to do this?

Comment: in that example above , it's a log in staging already, now I need to push only mine to production..while other git has aren't ready, for prod..and I need to have one commit only by combining all my git hash..so how?

Comment: So you have different branches for production and staging?

Comment: yes correct, the staging is meant to be our stable version, but then , the process is, push the commits that were already verified/qa passed in staging...now that mine were already verified, it's ready for production. but then other commits were built on top of mine which aren't yet ready for prod, that's why I need a way in order to pick only my commits and combine them in one commit only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`git rebase --interactive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) but, before you even start, please be aware of the negative effects of your action.

You intend to rewrite the history; this is not a bad thing *per se* but it can affect the other developers that work on the same project. If you do it and then push the changes to the central repository, you create a new history for the branch.

On your repo and on the central repo, this new history replaces the one you described in the question. But the repositories of the other developers don't know about the replacement and they think your branch (with its new history) is just a fork of the code that diverged from the history they know. When other developers try to pull the changes they will end up with a merge commit and possible with conflicts.

You can do it safely only if all the other devs know what you want to do, they don't push their changes until you finish the operation and then they correctly update their repositories before they continue working.

---

Enough with the warnings, let's see how you can do it.

First of all, make sure your repo is in a clean state. Use `git status` to learn about it. If it's not clean then commit or stash your changes before continuing.

The command to start modifying the history is:

```
git rebase --interactive asdfa
```

The argument of the `git rebase` command is the hash (or other identification way) of the last commit that is ok and doesn't need to be changed. I picked the hash of the last commit of other dev from your description.

When you run the command above, Git opens the editor you configured for it (the same it opens when you run `git commit`) with a file that looks like this:

```
pick adsf23 commit message #n
pick sdffdf commit message #2
...
pick asdadf commit message #1


# Rebase asdfa..asdadf onto asdfa (8 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
... more lines follow here ...
```

The file has two sections: the first part, the lines that start with `pick` contains the list of commits you want to rebase and the operations you want to do one them. The second part is in comments (each line starts with `#`) and contains directions about the operation. Read them and let them alone.

The commits are listed in their chronological order. The first one is the oldest one, the last one is the most recent.

Re-order the commit lines, put yours at the end of the list. Then, except from the for the first of your commits, replace `pick` with `squash`. Do not change anything else. Do not remove lines. If you remove a commit line, the corresponding commit is removed from the history. You probably don't want this happen.

Save the file and exit the editor. When you exit the editor, Git starts rebasing the commits using the directions you provided in the file. It goes back in history to the revision provided in the command line then applies the changes, one by one, as they are described in the file. It first applies the commits of the other devs then (because of `squash`) it combines all your commits into a single one and applies it.

It is possible that, during the operation, Git encounters a conflict because your commits introduce changes that overlaps with the commits of the other developers. In this situation Git stops, puts on screen the reason it stopped (the files that have conflicts) and directions how to continue.

If it's possible to fix the conflict you can continue (but it's possible to get more conflicts on the subsequent commits).

If you get too many conflicts and it's not possible to solve them, you can anytime abort the rebase using the command:

```
git rebase --abort
```

This restores your repository in the state it was when you started.

If your rebase completed with success and push it to the central repo, tell the other developers to run:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

on their repositories in order to get the new history correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not yet pushed the commits on the remote branch, you can use a combination of rebase and cherry-picking.

In order to do this you would have to rewrite the commit history.

One way to do this would be to create another branch from the start of your history.

```
git branch my_branch <first-commit>
```

Cherry-pick the commits

```
git cherry-pick <commit-A> <commit-B> ...
```

And then use interactive rebase to squash the commits

```
git rebase -i <after-this-commit>
```

Finally reintegrate the branch into your current branch.

Comment: I would use cherry-pick with the no-commit option, and then instead of using interactive rebase just make a normal commit.

Comment: can you please modify your answer? like i need a step by step...base it from the data example of my post please....noob here

Comment: @sasori Use what i have written as a base. I cannot / will not write everything as i don't have access to your command line. I strongly suggest that you try the commands in a local branch that you can delete / recreate if it does not work as expected. also use the --dry-run options before using git push. Final word read the documentation available for every command that you use :  git <command> --help

Comment: when you say re-integrate the branch, what do you mean? is it after this  `git rebase -i <after-this-commit>` , i do git push already ?

Comment: @sasori after you have squashed your commits, and you are okay with what you have done in the temporary branch, you will need to reintegrate the changes back into the remote branch. In order to do this, you would have to pull back the remote (on a master branch preferrably) and then rebase your commits on the master branch. Finally  use git push

Comment: @1615903 , can you elaborate what you meant by using cherry-pick without commit option ?